# Why do I receive different taken time in Weka in every modeling time?

Tags: java, classification, weka, data-mining, rweka

Every time I click start for do modeling in Weka for the same data and the same function I receive different taken time. How can I measure real taken time?

Answer (score 0):

Kill all other applications, including everything from your operating system. Then disable any graphical user interface.
Make sure to not use a modem CPU with turboboost.
Add extreme water cooling to prevent any kind of heat throttling.

Do not use the weka UI, but rather write a specialized Java program to benchmark that does a warm-up of the Hotspot VM, then runs several benchmarking runs with garbage collection inbetween for measurement. Then take the average of many runs.

Make sure to not use a randomly initialized algorithm, because that can affect runtime.

All of these factors (and many more) affect the observed runtime. So you can't get these to always return the same result in a point&click interface.